# Airflow chart sharing

Tags: airflow

Airflow documentation states that charts can be easily shared, but does not elaborate. I wish to send a weekly report containing all existing charts defined in the Airflow UI.

Can existing charts (created from the Airflow UI) be programmatically shared from a DAG? For example using the airflow.operators.EmailOperator. If so, how can they be accessed/generated (please provide an example if possible)?